# Accentbx not included in TeX and I'd really like to get the accentbx package but don't know how to add or install properly

Tags: accents

Let me preface by stating I'm still a newbie to TeX and my apologies in advance is if the solution to my problem is obvious.  So here's the issue.

I need to typeset characters with multiple accents, whereby their positions need to be exactly placed.  I'm working off this textbook, *Digital Typography Using LaTeX*, published by Springer.  In it there's a reference to a package, accentbx, which does seem to be a legit package: https://www.eutypon.gr/eutypon/pdf/e2000-05/e05-a04.pdf

Unfortunately, CTAN doesn't seem to include this within their MacTex package (I'm working off a mac) resulting in me having to manually install the .sty file, which I found off this site: https://github.com/zellyn/accentbx

Unfortunately, again, the sty file seems to bring up a plethora of errors, and I'm wondering if I'm doing anything wrong, or if there's something basic I'm not aware of.

This package seems like an amazing package considering what one can do with it.  The *accents* and *accenti* packages TeX comes configured in their latest build are not specific enough for my needs, in case anyone feels to suggest them.  What I want is accentbx, as developed by A.S. Berdnikov.

I'm in the process of emailing Berdnikov, based on that email he's left on the paper he wrote, but it's been many years, and it might be a longshot if he's not replying so I thought to write here in case someone can help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!